# How can I search two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a query that searches for a movie by title, actors, description etc and orders the results by movies that have the search term in the title.

```
select movie.id, movie.title  
from movie 
where 
title like '%searchTerm%' or
cast like '%searchTerm%' or
director like '%searchTerm%' or 
FullPlot like '%searchTerm%' 
order by (title like '%searchTerm%') desc ## this gives priority to results thatr have the search term in the title
```

Now I have a new table called "AlsoKnownAs". This table contains data about what movies are called in other languages. example Cidade De Deus (2003) AKA City Of God (2003)

I need to search this new table as well while i am searching for the movie and sort by it as secondary sort. so movies that contain the searchTerm in the AKA table will come after movies that contain searchTerm in the title.

I am not sure how to do this. It seems like i need to store the found term in a variable so that i can order by it.

any help welcome

```
AlsoKownAs table
'id', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'movieId', 'varchar(10)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'aka', 'varchar(305)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'country', 'varchar(100)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

Comment: perhaps instead of `AlsoKnownAs` you should just put all the titles in that table.

Comment: @DanielA.White i don't understand. put the titles in the movie table as a column?

Comment: no i mean put all of the titles for the movie in the `AlsoKnownAs` table

Comment: @DanielA.White can do that but still have the issue of searching both tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to return unique movies, then in addition to a left join you need to group by the id and title so you don't get duplicates for movies with multiple aka's.

You can use conditional aggregation to determine if any of the aka's matched and use that for your order

```
select id, title from (
    select t1.id, t1.title,
        sum(aka like '%searchTerm%') aka_count
    from movie t1
    left join AlsoKnownAs t2 on t1.id = t2.movieId
    where title like '%searchTerm%' 
    or cast like '%searchTerm%' 
    or director like '%searchTerm%'  
    or FullPlot like '%searchTerm%' 
    or aka like '%searchTerm%'
    group by t1.id, t1.title
) order by (title like '%searchTerm%') desc, (aka_count > 0) desc
```

**Edit**

It's probably faster to do a single table scan of the aka table and left join those results via a derived table:

```
select movie.id, movie.title  
from movie 
left join (
    select distinct movieId from AlsoKnownAs where aka like '%searchTerm%'
) t1 on t1.movieId = movie.id
where 
title like '%searchTerm%' or
cast like '%searchTerm%' or
director like '%searchTerm%' or 
FullPlot like '%searchTerm%' or
t1.movieId IS NOT NULL
order by (title like '%searchTerm%'), (t1.movieId IS NOT NULL) desc
```

Comment: the second one is fast. 3 seconds. what else do you think would make it faster?

Comment: @code578841441 the double wildcards prevent indexes from being used and force a table scan, so I don't see any more room for improvement

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you just need to join them. You can add `aka` as a field in *order by* (it will be secondary to original title though):

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, a.aka 
FROM movie m
LEFT JOIN AlsoKnownAs a ON m.id = a.movieId
WHERE 
   m.title like '%searchTerm%' or
   m.cast like '%searchTerm%' or
   m.director like '%searchTerm%' or 
   m.FullPlot like '%searchTerm%' or
   a.aka like '%searchTerm%' 
ORDER BY (m.title like '%searchTerm%') DESC, (a.aka like '%searchTerm%') DESC
```

*Disclaimer: My dbms is mssql, but I'm quite sure the syntax is the same in this query*

Comment: @code578841441  Then you probably want to index the `aka` field

Comment: index made it work but returns after 7 seconds. the other answer was a little faster at around 3 seconds. thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here, but wouldn't a simple `join` do the trick? :

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

So it would be:

```
select movie.id, movie.title, AlsoKownAs.aka
from movie 
left join AlsoKnowAs on movie.id = AlsoKnowAs.movieId
where 
title like '%searchTerm%'
-- .. rest skipped
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UNION clause to search in both tables.

```
select *
from (
    select 1 as qOrder, m.id, m.title, m.cast, m.director, m.fullplot 
    from movie m
    union
    select 2 as qorder, m.id, a.aka as title, m.cast, m.director, m.fullplot
    from akamovie a
    join movie m on a.movieid = m.id
) alltitles
where title like '%searchTerm%' or
    cast like '%searchTerm%' or
    director like '%searchTerm%' or 
    FullPlot like '%searchTerm%' 
order by qOrder asc, (title like '%searchTerm%') desc;
```